# Getting OpenCV headers to work correctly on install in Linux

Tags: linux, opencv, g++, c-preprocessor

I have an OpenCV installation on Ubuntu Linux. From any example the headers are:

```
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
```

When I compile with these includes I get the error :

```
fatal error: opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp: No such file or directory

#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
```

I can find out where OpenCV is located with

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
```

which outputs as follow:

```
 "Package opencv was not found"
```

When I try `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv2`

I get:

```
"Package opencv2 was not found"
```

Only when I use `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`  do I get the path:

```
-I/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2
```

so I thought that by changing the includes to:

```
#include <opencv4/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv4/highgui.hpp>
```

it would work. But I get:

```
fatal error: opencv4/imgcodecs.hpp: No such file or directory

#include <opencv4/imgcodecs.hpp>
```

so when I try the full path:

```
#include <opencv4/opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
```

I get:

```
imgcodecs.hpp:46:10: fatal error: opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory

#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
```

and of course in the `hpp` file in question it is:

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
```

Is there a simple way to fix all this?

Comment: The simplest way is to use a package manager like Conan

Comment: i am using a makefile and tried with Cmake with the same outcomes , now the crazy part is i have a  make file on another piece of code not written by me that works with #ifdef ,  i can share that as well

Comment: I prefer a package manager for development. It's difficult to manage the versions with system packages. Conan downloads the exact version and all its dependencies and sets all necessary paths. If you want it simple use Conan with CMake.

Answer (score 3):

I actually ran into this issue recently. The issue is that when you build OpenCV it places the header files in /usr/local/include/opencv4/ then underneath that you will see opencv2/opencv.hpp and all the other files you're referencing. To fix your issue you will need to run in bash:

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2 /usr/local/include/opencv2`

This resolved the issue for me, if it works for you please be sure to mark this as the answer.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. This can also be fixed by changing the build settings of  CMake before building openCV from source.

Comment: Solved the issue for me too. Thanks!