# How can I make OpenCV work properly in VS Code?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-code

I followed the tutorial from the official to install OpenCV, but first it could not find

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
```

but using the answer in this question [Getting OpenCV headers to work correctly on install in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62069386/getting-opencv-headers-to-work-correctly-on-install-in-linux), Visual Studio Code stops saying that the header was not found, but, when I try to follow the tutorial in de official page does not make the executable and  my terminal looks weird, like this

[image]

I don't know what else to do, I need for my final project, should I uninstall everything and follow another tutorial?

Comment: Did you install opencv via your package manager in linux?

Comment: ***Visual Studio Code stop saying that the header was not found*** Depending on where you installed opencv you may need to add the include path in your `c_cpp_properties.json` and your `tasks.json`

Comment: @drescherjm I used via terminal, I followed the quick start from https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html